# Best practice with regards to dynamically populated RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have an application with a `RecyclerView` populated by an `ArrayList` which I scrape from a website. As I have it structured currently, the relevant `fragment` containing the `RecyclerView` contains an `AsyncTask` and thus the data is scraped in the `fragment's` `onCreate` method. The RecyclerView is then populated in the `AsyncTask's onPostExecute`. Now, the thing is, this often leads to my application crashing at randomly simply because the data from the `AsyncTask` scraper returns `null`. Furthermore, it seems to me as though this approach is unnecessarily complex and could be streamlined. Thus, my question is what is generally regarded as the most efficient and simplest method for populating a `RecyclerView` with scraped data? (note: I also have a `TabLayout` which changes the url of the data being scraped and thus I have to either r-escrape the data for each tab's `fragment` (and each time the user reopens the relevant `NavigationDrawer` section), or somehow restructure my application so that this becomes unnecessary. Any help is appreciated!

**My RefresherFragment class:**

```
public class RefresherFragment extends Fragment{

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
public String markingPeriod;

public static RefresherFragment newInstance(String markingPeriod){
    RefresherFragment instance = new RefresherFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("mp", markingPeriod);
    instance.setArguments(bundle);
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    markingPeriod = getArguments().getString("mp");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mp_refresher_fragment, container, false);

    new Scraper(markingPeriod).execute();

    Log.e("RefresherFragment", "MP=" + markingPeriod);

    return view;
}

//fragment setup-------------------------------------------------------------------------

public ArrayList<String> extractClasses (Document document){
    ArrayList<String> classList = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements elements = document.select(".categorytab");
    for (Element element : elements){
        classList.add(element.text().toString());
    }
    return classList;
}

public ArrayList<String> extractGrades (Document document){
    ArrayList<String> keepList = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements elements = document.select(".cellRight");
    for (Element element : elements){
        boolean keep = true;
        for (Element e : element.parents()){
            if (e.hasClass("cellRight")){
                keep = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (keep){
            keepList.add(element.text().toString());
        }
    }
    return keepList;
}

public class Wrapper{
    Document document;
    Elements elements;
}


private class Scraper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    String mMarkingPeriod;

    public Scraper(String mp) {
        mMarkingPeriod = mp;
    }

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();

        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());
        String username = sessionManager.getUsername();
        String password = sessionManager.getPassword();


        DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(username,password);
        Map<String, String> preLoginCookies = dataManager.getPreLoginCookies(mMarkingPeriod);
        Map<String, String> postLoginCookies = dataManager.getPostLoginCookies(preLoginCookies);
        Document doc = dataManager.getDocumentByMP(postLoginCookies,mMarkingPeriod);

        if (doc == null){
            Log.e("doInBackground Check", "null");}

        Elements elements = doc.select(".cellRight");

        wrapper.document = doc;
        wrapper.elements = elements;

        return wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper wrapper) {

        Document document = wrapper.document;
        ArrayList <String> grades = extractGrades(document);
        ArrayList <String> classes = extractClasses(document);


        for (String classElement : classes){
            Log.e("Class", classElement);
        }

        for (String gradeElement : grades){
            Log.e("Grade", gradeElement);
        }
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "Iterating elements");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grade_recycler);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new GradeRecyclerAdapter(classes, grades));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "Setting up Recycler");

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.refresher);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Scraper(getArguments().getString("mp")).execute();
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What’s the question? The best practice is that if you can’t load your data, you should show a “Can’t load data” message.

Comment: @natario I'm asking whether it would be better to use a different structure given that it seems inefficient to rescrape data every time I instantiate a fragment

Comment: You mean that when user moves from one tab to another, and then back to the first, scraping runs twice?

Comment: Every time the `fragment` is instantiated, the Scraper runs, the `RecyclerView` is instantiated, and is then populated by the data from the Scraper